# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occur when call stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net

Additional information: Could not find server 'SS2008' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure `sp_addlinkedserver` to add the server to sys.servers.

this is my connection string

> "data source=123-pc;initial catalog=Inquire_Commerce;user id=sa;password=sasasa;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework"

here is my code

```
var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "dbo.AdvancedProductSearch";
cmd.CommandTimeout = 90;
cmd.Connection.Open();
AddParameter(cmd, "searchtext", queryParameters.Keyword);
AddParameter(cmd, "pagesize", queryParameters.PageSize);
AddParameter(cmd, "pageno", queryParameters.PageNo);
AddParameter(cmd, "attributevalues", queryParameters.AttNamValue);

AddParameter(cmd, "word1", word1);
AddParameter(cmd, "word2", word2);
AddParameter(cmd, "word3", word3);
AddParameter(cmd, "word4", word4);
AddParameter(cmd, "word5", word5);
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
```

and i got this error in this line

```
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code. Are you calling this stored procedure against a different server than SS2008 ?

Comment: i got error on this line  "var reader=cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);"

Comment: Well, and what did you do? Stare on the screen without trying to solve it? The error actually tells you what the error may be and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely not a coding problem but a problem in SQL Linked Servers Configuration. Look at the content of the stored procedure that you're calling. There will be a statement (`SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` etc.), that refers to a row source on a linked server that is named `SS2008`. Make sure that on the SQL Server you're connecting to, a linked server by that name exists, and is accessible.

Comment: connection is fine other queries are working fine.